# execute grep regular expression involving `|` using ssh on remote host

Tags: bash, ssh, grep

I am trying to run grep command involving regular expression '|' on a server using ssh.

`ssh rpatil@192.168.1.5 grep -E "GapEvent|GapFilled" "$logFile" > $server-$testName.log`

now `'|'` in the command is being treated as pipe and error `"no command GapFilled"` is being raised.

I tried `'GapEvent|GapFilled'` or `'(GapEvent|GapFilled)'`

so how should regular expression `"GapEvent|GapFilled"` should be written so that `|` is not treated as pipe?

Comment: Try `grep -P "GapEvent|GapFilled" "$logFile"`

Comment: sorry, it is still same error. bash: GapFilled: command not found

Comment: backslash it `\|` or single quotes

Answer (score 2):

You need two levels of quotes since the command line is evaluated twice (once locally when `ssh` is executed and once when `grep` is executed on the remote side). You can use one of these patterns:

```
  "'a|b'"
  '"a|b"'
  "\"a|b\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `|` like this  `\|`

```
grep -E "GapEvent\|GapFilled" "$logFile" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use two expressions:

```
grep -E -e "GapEvent" -e "GapFilled" "$logFile"
```

`-E` may no longer be needed here. `-F` may also be a preference.